# https://www. to https:// redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect https://www to https://

I've tried every possible snippet of code I could find online to do that over .htaccess

The best one seemed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

But it's not working for me.

Nothing I do has any effect. If I type https://www.danielleb.com/ - that's where I remain.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: ;-) come on starkeen

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using and it works fine for redirecting https://www. to https://

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```